# Return multiples tables with procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I apologize if the title for the question doesn't match what I am asking what to do.  I am not sure how to describe what I am trying to accomplish.

I have the following tables in my database:

```
Table customers
    customer_id (PK, int, NN)
    customer_name (varchar(100), NN)

Table jobs
    job_id (PK, int, NN)
    job_number (varchar(10), NN)
    job_description (varchar(MAX), NN)
    customer_id (FK, int, NN)

Table job_statuses
    status_id (PK, int, NN)
    status_description (varchar(50), NN)

Table job_status_logs
    log_id (PK, int, NN)
    job_id (FK, int, NN)
    status_id (FK, int, NN)
    log_date (date, NN)
```

Now I am trying to program a procedure where I pass it a Job Number and it does the following:

1) Checks if the Job Number exists within the database, if not, return an error message.

2) If the Job Number exists return the following columns from the following tables:

```
jobs: job_id, job_number, job_description
customers: customer_name
job_status_logs: log_date (WHERE status_description is 'Open') & log_date (WHERE status_description is 'Closed')
```

I am mainly having an issue with the very last part, as I am unsure how to form the query looking for the last two points of data (the ones from the `job_status_logs` table).

EDIT: This is currently what I have for the procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetJobData(
    @JobNum   VARCHAR(10),
    @response NVARCHAR(500) OUTPUT
) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @JobID INT
    SELECT @JobID = job_id
      FROM jobs
     WHERE job_number = @JobNum
    IF @JobID IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @response = 'Cannot find data for Job "' + @JobNum + '".  Job does not exist.'
        RETURN
    END
    SELECT j.job_id AS [ID], j.job_number AS [Job], j.job_description AS [Description], c.customer_name AS [Customer]
      FROM jobs AS j INNER JOIN
           customer AS c ON c.customer_id = j.customer_id
     WHERE j.job_id = @JobID
END
GO
```

As stated above, I do not know *how* to set up the query to grab the data I am looking for from the `job_status_logs` table.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and show what you have tried so far.

Comment: @PeterB my question is that I literally don't know how to formulate the query to get the data I am looking for.  So me posting what I have tried, is me posting what in my question I said I already know how to do.

Comment: Did you mean status_description instead of status_id in the last WHERE clause you provided? Because status_id is integer and you are trying to compare it with strings such as Open or Close.

Comment: @BahtiyarSametÇoban yes, I did mean description, will edit that

Comment: @Skitzafreak - what do you want to see if the job was opened, but never closed?  Is that possible?

Comment: @ScottHodgin If the job was opened, but not closed (yes that is possible) I'd want to get the date it was opened, and receive a null value for the closed date (since it doesn't exist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - there are two examples.  The first result (jobid=100) has both and open and a closed logdate.  The second result (jobid=200) only has an open logdate.  Take note of the `LEFT JOIN` against the 'closed' statuses.

```
--demo setup
DECLARE @customers TABLE (
    customer_id INT
    ,customer_name VARCHAR(100)
    )
insert into @customers(customer_id,customer_name) values(1,'bob')

DECLARE @jobs TABLE (
    job_id INT
    ,job_number VARCHAR(10)
    ,job_description VARCHAR(MAX)
    ,customer_id INT
    )
insert into @jobs(job_id,job_number,job_description,customer_id) values
(1,'100','jobdesc',1),(2,'200','jobdesc2',1)

DECLARE @job_statuses TABLE (
    status_id INT
    ,status_description VARCHAR(50)
    )
insert into @job_statuses(status_id,status_description) values(1,'open'),(2,'closed')

DECLARE @job_status_logs TABLE (
    log_id INT
    ,job_id INT
    ,status_id INT
    ,log_date DATE
    )
insert into @job_status_logs(log_id, job_id,status_id,log_date) values
(1,1,1,'2018-10-01'),(2,1,2,'2018-11-01'),(3,2,1,'2018-12-01')
```

---

```
--the solution
--parameter passed into SP
DECLARE @JobNumber INT

SET @JobNumber = 100    --has both open and closed status

SELECT j.job_id
    ,j.job_number
    ,j.job_description
    ,c.customer_name
    ,jslo.log_date AS LogOpen
    ,jslc.log_date AS LogClosed
FROM @jobs j
JOIN @customers c
    ON c.customer_id = j.customer_id
JOIN (
    SELECT jsl.job_id
        ,log_date
    FROM @job_status_logs jsl
    JOIN @job_statuses js
        ON js.status_id = jsl.status_id
            AND js.status_description = 'open'
    ) jslo
    ON jslo.job_id = j.job_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT jsl.job_id
        ,log_date
    FROM @job_status_logs jsl
    JOIN @job_statuses js
        ON js.status_id = jsl.status_id
            AND js.status_description = 'closed'
    ) jslc
    ON jslc.job_id = j.job_id
WHERE j.job_number = @JobNumber

---------------------------

SET @JobNumber = 200    --has only open status

SELECT j.job_id
    ,j.job_number
    ,j.job_description
    ,c.customer_name
    ,jslo.log_date AS LogOpen
    ,jslc.log_date AS LogClosed
FROM @jobs j
JOIN @customers c
    ON c.customer_id = j.customer_id
JOIN (
    SELECT jsl.job_id
        ,log_date
    FROM @job_status_logs jsl
    JOIN @job_statuses js
        ON js.status_id = jsl.status_id
            AND js.status_description = 'open'
    ) jslo
    ON jslo.job_id = j.job_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT jsl.job_id
        ,log_date
    FROM @job_status_logs jsl
    JOIN @job_statuses js
        ON js.status_id = jsl.status_id
            AND js.status_description = 'closed'
    ) jslc
    ON jslc.job_id = j.job_id
WHERE j.job_number = @JobNumber
```

---

Result1

```
| job_id | job_number | job_description | customer_name | LogOpen    | LogClosed  |
|--------|------------|-----------------|---------------|------------|------------|
| 1      | 100        | jobdesc         | bob           | 2018-10-01 | 2018-11-01 |
```

Result2

```
| job_id | job_number | job_description | customer_name | LogOpen    | LogClosed |
|--------|------------|-----------------|---------------|------------|-----------|
| 2      | 200        | jobdesc2        | bob           | 2018-12-01 | NULL      |
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I didn't know you could join a subquery, so that's something new I learned today :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you meant status_description instead of status_id in the last sentence.
Your need is really unclear to me still, I think you want to return one column in the result set and it will be either [OpenDate] or [ClosedDate] according to job status description.

I have deleted my procedure and added necessary changes to your existing procedure. Now, it return a column either [OpenDate]  or [ClosedDate].

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetJobData(
    @JobNum   VARCHAR(10),
    @response NVARCHAR(500) OUTPUT
) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @JobID INT
    SELECT @JobID = job_id
      FROM jobs
     WHERE job_number = @JobNum
    IF @JobID IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @response = 'Cannot find data for Job "' + @JobNum + '".  Job does not exist.'
        RETURN
    END


    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM jobs j INNER JOIN customers c on j.customer_id=c.customer_id 
    INNER JOIN job_status_logs jl on j.job_id=jl.job_id
    INNER JOIN job_statuses js on jl.status_id=js.status_id
    where j.job_number=@JobNum
    and js.status_description ='Open')
    BEGIN
    SELECT j.job_id, j.job_number, j.job_description,c.customer_name
    ,jl.log_date as [OpenDate] 
    FROM jobs j
    inner JOIN customers c on j.customer_id=c.customer_id 
    inner JOIN job_status_logs jl on j.job_id=jl.job_id
    inner JOIN job_statuses js on jl.status_id=js.status_id
    where j.job_number=@JobNum
    and js.status_description ='Open' 
    END
    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM jobs j INNER JOIN customers c on j.customer_id=c.customer_id 
    INNER JOIN job_status_logs jl on j.job_id=jl.job_id
    INNER JOIN job_statuses js on jl.status_id=js.status_id
    where j.job_number=@JobNum
    and js.status_description ='Closed')
    BEGIN
    SELECT j.job_id, j.job_number, j.job_description,c.customer_name
    ,jl.log_date as [ClosedDate] 
    FROM jobs j
    inner JOIN customers c on j.customer_id=c.customer_id 
    inner JOIN job_status_logs jl on j.job_id=jl.job_id
    inner JOIN job_statuses js on jl.status_id=js.status_id
    where j.job_number=@JobNum
    and js.status_description ='Closed' 
    END
END
GO
```

Comment: You made a correct assumption for my typo, which I fixed in the OP.  The issue I am having, is I am not looking for just when `status_description` is Equal to 'Open' or 'Closed'.  I specifically need to select the entry for 'Open' AND the entry for 'Closed'.

Comment: so you want to understand whether it is open or closed for a job number you are sending to procedure, am I correct? If that is the case, i will update the procedure with union all case.

Comment: If you see the edit I made to the OP to include what I currently have for the procedure, I essentially want to be able to output a column named 'OpenDate' with the date where the `status_description` is 'Open' and a column named 'CloseDate' where the `status_description` is 'Closed'.

Comment: I edited your SP to return 1 column only as you wanted. If you want to return two columns (OpenDate and CloseDate) for each job result set, this needs to be edited again.